# Запись математических формул на языке HTML

Tags: javascript, html, математика

Только не смейтесь над вопросом. Можно ли использовать этот язык для полноценной записи формул?

---

Не пойму. [Здесь](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-in-html-documents) показано, как установить знак доллара в качестве математического разделителя, а у меня не получается:

```html
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
    processEscapes: true
  }
});
<script 

<script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
    
$\sqrt{p+1}$ падать
\(\sqrt{p+1}\)
```

Это опять у меня браузеры косячат, или действительно код ошибочный?

Comment: может это Вам поможет (нажмите на кнопку render по ссылке) https://quicklatex.com/

Comment: [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/math), [2](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/maths.html).

Comment: StrangerintheQ, я про это знаю, но это для меня является не очень приемлемо. Вот если бы тот сайт можно было как-нибудь подключить к моему блогу, чтоб ничего не копировать, а прям в блоге пишешь формулу на LaTeX и при публикации сообщения получаешь красивую формулу. @AlexanderPetrov, скажите, пожалуйста, особенно как сказано во второй ссылке, это работает на blogger?

Comment: Проба: 
<MATH>&int;_a_^b^{f (x)<over>1 + x}dx</MATH>

Comment: Нет, что-то не то, хотя на Блоггере при добавленном в поперечный столбец гаджете HTML/Javascript тэги при публикации исчезают.

Comment: Ну, так не поможете это все подключить? А то эти все общие фразы...

Comment: @Grek79, зря вы думаете что это смешно.. Очень хороший вопрос. Я вот раньше не задумывался об этом, благодаря вам буду знать)

Comment: Я вообще не смеялся. Ладно. Другое. Так, просто интересно. Вчера через какие-то сторонние сайты я на сайте mathjax выходил на файл с расширением .exe (сегодня не могу найти, хотя история браузеров обшарил). Это же нужно устанавливать дополнительную программу, чтобы можно было на своем компе пользоваться mathjax при отсутствии Интернета?

Comment: _blogger, твиттер_ - э-э-э, что? Не вижу этого в **вопросе**. Вы спросили: "Можно ли использовать html для записи математеческих формул", вы получили ответ: "Да, можно". Если вас интересует, можно ли использовать html для записи формул на какой-либо платформе, то так и спросите. И лучше всего спросить это в техподдержке той платформы, разрешают ли они рендеринг _всех_ тегов html у себя.

Comment: Дополню: в комментариях stackoverflow не поддерживаются практически все теги html, поэтому тестить что-то в комментах нет смысла [link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). В теле вопросов-ответов поддерживаются тоже далеко не все теги: [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: А что, развить тему нельзя?

Answer (score 7):

Вот какое-то такое решение Вам наверняка подойдет:

---

https://www.mathjax.org/

```html
<script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
<h2>$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$</h2>
```

---

https://github.com/mathquill

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.css" />
<span id="problem">ax^2 + \sqrt{bx} + \frac{3}{2}c = 0</span>
<script>
  var MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2);
  MQ.StaticMath(document.getElementById('problem'));
</script>
```

Comment: Вы же это [вот здесь](https://html-shark.com/HTML/Equations.htm) прочитали? Я найти-то нашел, а ума не дал. Большущее спасибо. Я об этом тоже напишу в блоге.

Comment: А в Твиттере не работает, ну, да, ладно, еще раз сенкс.

Comment: @Grek79 нет я загулглил https://www.google.com/search?q=js+render+latex

Comment: а второй код в ответе не работает даже здесь.а второй код в ответе не работает даже здесь. а второй код в ответе не работает даже здесь.

Comment: @ StrangerintheQ, а второй код в ответе не работает даже здесь.

Comment: @Grek79 у меня в chrome + windows работает

Comment: У меня тоже самое... Слушайте, а как писать к вам обращение? Я когда пишу слитно с собачкой, обращение пропадает.

Comment: Под моим сообщением  это не нужно, они автоматически приходят мне

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91875/discussion-between-grek79-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Comment: А что делать с файлами `.zip`, [выложенными здесь](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html), не подскажите?

Comment: @Grek79 это необходимо, если Вы хотите получать эти скрипты со своего сервера, в интернете это не нужно, это больше для закрытых сетей возможность

Comment: В том числе и для работы на компах, не подключенных к Инету?

Comment: Кстати, я нашел [способ еще лучше](http://kaktusenok.blogspot.com/2011/12/blogger.html). Так не нужно подключать к каждой странице, а настраиваешь только раз.

Comment: @Grek79 а Вы знаете про github pages?

Comment: @Grek79 я там держу кое какие поделки и там нет никаких ограничений, сами делаете как Вам надо https://strangerintheq.github.io/mandelbrot.html?eyJ4IjotMC4wNDk3MDA5MDQ2NjIwMTI5MSwieSI6LTAuMDc0MDExNzQ1MTE1MDAwNTEsImkiOiIyNTYiLCJhIjoiNTAiLCJiIjoiNTAiLCJ0IjoiMTAiLCJ6IjoxLjM0ODYzOTc5ODE4OTA4OTYsImZvcm11bGEiOiJlaUE5SUcxMWJDaDZMQ0I2S1NBcklHTXJkQ293TGpFNyJ9

Comment: Нет. аааааааааа

Comment: А вот это, я тот блог просто создал. У меня же там нет сервера?

Comment: @Grek79 сервер есть, просто его содержимое напрямую вы менять не можете

Comment: А, скажем, Яндекс диск подойдет в качестве сервера?

Comment: @Grek79 наверняка есть и такая возможность, я использую гитхаб

Comment: StrangerintheQ, а вы, вообще, с Tex'ом знакомы?

Comment: @Grek79 +-, я далек от математической записи формул, я проще понимаю код.

Answer (score 4):

Нашел:

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({ TeX: { extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js"] }});
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
    processEscapes: true
  }
});
</script>

<script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
$x_{1,\,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ что-то написано  $\dfrac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}=\dfrac{d\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dx}$
```

Заменил ссылку.

Comment: [А вот здесь](https://upmath.me/) еще и вставку tikz поддерживает!

Answer (score 0):

Я тут покопался. Нашел похожее решение. Но, к сожалению, не все его части здесь функционируют:

```html
<script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
\(\frac{1}{2}\) /*проверки для*/
\(\require{color}\) 
\(\color{green}{p}\) /*цвет подключить удалось*/
\(\require{bbox}\) 
\(\bbox[red,2pt]{x+1}\) /*а вот bbox -нет*/
```

А так, решение такое:

```html
<script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
\(\frac{1}{2}\) /*чисто для проверки*/
/*А решение вот:*/
\(\bbox[0.5mm,black]{\textcolor{white}{\mbox{Shift}}}+\bbox[0.5mm,black]{\textcolor{white}{\mbox{A}}}\)
```

В результате получаю вот что :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите, пожалуйста, вот со стороны так глаза не очень режет? Хотел уголки у клавиш закруглить. Но почему-то секунду после загрузки страницы они, действительно закруглены, а потом становятся прямыми.